# CakePHP 2.3 Model probleme getting data

Tags: cakephp

sorry for my english and i'm new using CAKEPHP 2.3

i get a problem using model association where i can't get "joined data" ( i understand that cakephp get automatically joined data if models are set good , obviously i make it wrong )

---

I have 2 tables in my database:

**departements** (with the following columns)

-id

-name

-region_id   ( region_id is a foreign key on regions(id) )

**regions** (with the following columns)

-id

-name

---

i make two models in cakePhp:

Region.php

```
<?php
class Region extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Region';
    var $actsAs = array( 'Containable' );
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Departement' => array(
            'className' => 'Departement',
            'foreignKey' => 'region_id',
            'dependent' => false
        )
    );
}

?>
```

Departement.php

```
<?php
class Departement extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Departement';
    var $actsAs = array( 'Containable' );

    public $belongsTo=array(
        'Region' => array(
            'className' => 'Region',
            'foreignKey' => 'region_id',
            'dependent' => false
        )
    );
}
?>
```

---

in a another controller where i need departements and regions, i tryed many thinks but after yours i need your help please !!!

i make this :
first attempt:

```
<?php
class SignalementsController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
    var $name = 'Signalements';
    var $uses = array('Signalements','Regions','Departements','Communes');

    public $recursive = 4;  

    public function index() { 
           $departements = $this->Departements->find('all');
           $this->set('departements', $departements);
    }
}
```

who output in the index view:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Departements' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'name' => 'AIN',
            'region_id' => '82'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'Departements' => array(
            'id' => '10',
            'name' => 'AUBE',
            'region_id' => '21'
        )
    )
...
)
```

but there is no region joined automatically

second attempt: i change the find models from

```
$regions = $this->Regions->find('all');
$this->set('regions', $regions);
```

who output :

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Regions' => array(
            'id' => '11',
            'name' => 'ILE-DE-FRANCE'
        )
    ), ... );
```

but there is no departements joined automatically

last

```
$fields=array('Region.id','Region.nom','Departement.id','Departement.nom');
$all= $this->Regions->Departements->find('all',$fields);
/* or all this not working as execpted
$all= $this->Departements->Regions->find('all',$fields);
$all= $this->Departements->find('all',$fields);
$all= $this->Regions->find('all',$fields);
*/
$this->set('all', $all);
```

---

i try  to get the regions data inside each departemts for exemple like this

```
 array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Departements' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'nom' => 'AIN',
            'region' => array(  'id' => '82', 'nom' => 'POITOU-CHARENTES')
        )
    ),
```

but i get only this :

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Departements' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'nom' => 'AIN',
            'region_id' => '82'
        )
    ),
```

---

If you have any idea please leave it
thank you very much

Comment: did you try setting your recursive to 1 ?

Comment: thanks for the help. i tryed but same thing.
in the sql dumps there is no join:
SELECT `Departements`.`id`, `Departements`.`nom`, `Departements`.`region_id` FROM `signalement_albopictus`.`departements` AS `Departements`
2 SELECT `Regions`.`id`, `Regions`.`nom` FROM `signalement_albopictus`.`regions` AS `Regions`

Comment: As Ayo said one problem is the recursiveness of 5. Since they dependend on each it needs a lot of queries. Each Region found would query its Department which in turn queries its region...etc.

Comment: i change the public $recursive = 1; but same thing.

Comment: Can it be that one of your ID fields is a text/varchar and not a integer (as it should be)?

Comment: i damn you right,
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `departements` (
  `id` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `nom` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `region_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  KEY `fk_departement_region1_idx` (`region_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

i change this now

Comment: in your index function, you should have $this->Departements->recursive = 1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [`Containable`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) behaviour in your model, so try the find with this:

```
$departements = $this->Departement->find('all', array('contain' => 'Region'));
```

Also the maximum level for [`recursive`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive) is 2, setting it to 4 (or 1000) has the effect of 2.

Comment: thanks but after trying i still stuck :
`(int) 0 => array(

  'Departements' => array(
   'id' => '1',
   'nom' => 'AIN',
   'region_id' => '82'
  )
 ),`

Comment: $mysql = $this->Departements->query("SELECT `departements`.`nom`,`regions`.`nom` FROM `departements`,`regions` WHERE `departements`.`region_id` = `regions`.`id` order by `departements`.`id`");

I try this and this work, i will used this until i find a solution

Comment: Your Model has to be singular, your table plural. How is `$this->Departements` (notice, plural) work in the first place? It has to be `$this->Departement`

Comment: Yes you are wright. I was working without outputing error. I change to singular name models and i get finaly thé join!!

Comment: Yes you are wright. It was working without outputing error( and without exepted results) I change to singular name models and i get finaly thé join!!

Comment: Thanks everybody for your precious Time and help

Comment: Glad it worked, remember to upvote the good answers or comments and mark the solution that worked for you as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

**Your ID is of type varchar and should be int.**

Also, here is a stripped down version of your code

**Region.php**

```
<?php
class Region extends AppModel {
    var $actsAs = array( 'Containable' );
    public $hasMany = array( 'Departement' );
}
?>
```

**Departement.php**

```
<?php
class Departement extends AppModel {
    var $actsAs = array( 'Containable' );
    public $belongsTo=array( 'Region' );
}
?>


<?php
class SignalementsController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
    var $uses = array('Signalements','Regions','Departements','Communes');

    public function index() { 
           $this->Departement->recursive = 1;
           $departements = $this->Departements->find('all');
           $this->set('departements', $departements);
    }
}
```

**index.ctp**

```
<?php print_r($departements); ?>
```

What does it give you?

Comment: i modifed my database to have all the id in INT(11).
but same think unfortunatly
    `array(
     (int) 0 => array(
  'Departements' => array(
   'id' => '1',
   'nom' => 'AIN',
   'region_id' => '82'
  )
 ),`

Comment: in DB, between regions and departements it's a 'non identyfing relationship'.

Comment: As the other answer already said I did not see that you were using the plural to query the model. It has to be singular :S Post edited.